# How to get selected color based on checked radio in card

Tags: html, jquery

I can obtain the theme value for the checked radio, but the colour always returns the value from the first card.

For example, when I checked for theme 3 and selected the colour pink, the outcome that was returned was the colour green. The colour value will change if I change it in theme 1.

Can anyone help me with this? I've tried many ways but I still cannot get my desired result. Here is my [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j60mk7n9/1/)

```js
$('.layout_style').on('click', 'li>a', function() {
  $(this).closest('.theme').find('a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  //console.log($(this).attr('data-color'))
});

$(document).on('click', '#SaveTheme', function() {
  var Theme = $('input[name="theme"]:checked').val();
  var ThemeColor = $('.layout_style').find(".active").data("color")
  console.log(Theme)
  console.log(ThemeColor)
});
```

```css
.row>div {
  position: relative
}

.card {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(8, 21, 66, 0.05);
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(8, 21, 66, 0.05)
}

.product-box {
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden
}

.product-box .product-details {
  padding: 10px 25px
}

.product-box .product-details p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0.8
}

.theme li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  margin: 0 2px
}

.theme_menu ul.theme li a:hover,
.theme_menu ul.theme li a.active {
  background: #f9f9f9;
}

.theme_menu ul.theme li {
  margin: 0 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}

.theme.layout_style li a {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.theme.layout_style li a.active {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
  transform: scale(0.75);
}

.theme_menu ul.theme li a {
  display: block;
}

.tx-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-xl-3 col-sm-6'>
    <div class='card'>
      <div class='product-box'>
        <div class='product-img tx-center'>
          <img class='img-fluid ' height="120" src='https://iconarchive.com/download/i109565/cjdowner/cryptocurrency-flat/ICON-ICX.ico' alt=''></div>
        <div class='product-details'>
          <div class='theme_menu'>
            <ul class='theme layout_style tx-center'>
              <li>
                <a data-color='green' style='background-color: #78cc6d' class='active'></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a data-color='blue' style='background-color: rgba(8, 86, 193, 1);'></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a data-color='orange' style='background-color: rgba(255, 152, 0, 1)'></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a data-color='pink' style='background-color: rgba(255, 94, 148, 1)'></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a data-color='purple' style='background-color: rgba(196, 70, 218, 1)'></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a data-color='red' style='background-color: rgba(232, 103, 107, 1)'></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class='form-check radio radio-primary tx-center'>
            <input class='form-check-input' id='radio0' type='radio' name='theme' value='theme1'>
            <label class='form-check-label' for='radio0'>Theme 1</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='col-xl-3 col-sm-6'>
    <div class='card'>
      <div class='product-box'>
        <div class='product-img tx-center'>
          <img class='img-fluid' height="120" src='https://iconarchive.com/download/i109565/cjdowner/cryptocurrency-flat/ICON-ICX.ico' alt=''></div>
        <div class='product-details'>
          <div class='theme_menu'>
            <ul class='theme layout_style tx-center'>
              <li>
                <a data-color='green' style='background-color: #78cc6d' class='active'></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a data-color='blue' style='background-color: rgba(8, 86, 193, 1);'></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a data-color='orange' style='background-color: rgba(255, 152, 0, 1)'></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a data-color='pink' style='background-color: rgba(255, 94, 148, 1)'></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a data-color='purple' style='background-color: rgba(196, 70, 218, 1)'></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a data-color='red' style='background-color: rgba(232, 103, 107, 1)'></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class='form-check radio radio-primary tx-center'>
            <input class='form-check-input' id='radio1' type='radio' name='theme' value='theme2'>
            <label class='form-check-label' for='radio1'>Theme 2</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='col-xl-3 col-sm-6'>
    <div class='card'>
      <div class='product-box'>
        <div class='product-img tx-center'>
          <img class='img-fluid' height="120" src='https://iconarchive.com/download/i109565/cjdowner/cryptocurrency-flat/ICON-ICX.ico' alt=''></div>
        <div class='product-details'>
          <div class='theme_menu'>
            <ul class='theme layout_style tx-center'>
              <li>
                <a data-color='green' style='background-color: #78cc6d' class='active'></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a data-color='blue' style='background-color: rgba(8, 86, 193, 1);'></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a data-color='orange' style='background-color: rgba(255, 152, 0, 1)'></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a data-color='pink' style='background-color: rgba(255, 94, 148, 1)'></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a data-color='purple' style='background-color: rgba(196, 70, 218, 1)'></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a data-color='red' style='background-color: rgba(232, 103, 107, 1)'></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class='form-check radio radio-primary tx-center'>
            <input class='form-check-input' id='radio1' type='radio' name='theme' value='theme3'>
            <label class='form-check-label' for='radio1'>Theme 3</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="SaveTheme">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code:

```
$('.layout_style').on('click', 'li>a', function() {
  $(this).closest('.theme').find('a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  //console.log($(this).attr('data-color'))
});

$(document).on('click', '#SaveTheme', function() {
  var Theme = $('input[name="theme"]:checked').val();
  var ThemeColor = $('input[name="theme"]:checked').closest('.product-details').find(".layout_style .active").data("color")
  console.log(Theme)
  console.log(ThemeColor)
});
```